# Floor function issue

Tags: warning-messages, recursion

While attempting to evaluate a recurrence relation an error with the Floor function is encountered. Computing an example to verify the floor function works correctly I ran the code

`Table[n + Floor[(n + 1)/2], {n, 0, 10}]`

and obtained `{0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 12, 14, 15}` which is the expected result. Now, while attempting to run the code

`RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == a[n] + Floor[(n + 1)/2], a[0] == 0}, a, {n, 0, 20}]`

the error `RecurrenceTable::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of False in the first argument {a[1+n]==a[n]+Floor[(1+n)/2],False}. >>` appears. Other instances of utilizing the Floor function in a similar manor lead to error messages similar to this one. Is there a fix, or work around that will eliminate the error?

The attempted goal is to calculate the terms defined by the code

`RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == a[n] + Floor[Log10[a[n]]] + 1, a[1] == 1}, a, {n, 1, 20}]`

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Perhaps you have left over definitions? Try quitting the kernel and trying again.

Comment: @march I have repeated the start, quit, (and restart machine), process over the past few days. I had run the code on MA 7, 9, 10 and all have errors. I can run the code in Wolfram Alpha and get the data.

Comment: Your RecurrenceTable code runs fine here too (10.3, Mac os 10.11)

Comment: Could you confirm, run ClearAll["Global`*"] prior to executing any code, does it result in error?

Comment: In your notebook, is the identifier `a` colored blue? If not, then you have made `a` a constant and it will no longer function as variable. Try `Clear @ a` before running your code.

Comment: Code works fine for me (v. 10.3).

Comment: @E.Doroskevic Your tip has helped end my frustration. Thanks.

Comment: @m_goldberg In the code there is no issue of `a` being blue, nor other issues besides the error presented.

Comment: But `a` should be blue. That means it is unassigned, which you need.

Comment: @m_goldberg You are correct `a` and `n` are blue. I applied the `ClearAll["Global`*"]` and `Clear@a` before running the codes and the errors have been removed. The codes run as expected.

Comment: Just a heads up, instead of `Floor[Log10[a[n]]] + 1`, `IntegerLength[a[n]]` could be used; `IntegerLength` is a faster way to obtain the same results.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem has not been reproducible outside the OP's own environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code:**

```
RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == a[n] + Floor[(n + 1)/2], 
  a[0] == 0}, a, {n, 0, 20}]
```

**Output:**

> {0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 9, 12, 16, 20, 25, 30, 36, 42, 49, 56, 64, 72, 81, 90, 100}

**Note:**

Make sure that no variable which you use within the function [RecurrenceTable](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RecurrenceTable.html#165200199) is previously defined. Use **ClearAll["Global`*"]** to clear scope from existing variable definitions.

Answer (score 1):

BTW,

```
RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == a[n] + Floor[Log10[a[n]]], a[1] == 1}, a, {n, 1, 20}]
```

is rather uninteresting. It gives

> `{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}`

because `Floor[Log10[a[1]]]` is zero and the recurrence goes nowhere.

#### Update

Evaluating the indicated revision of the question,

```
RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == a[n] + 1 + Floor[Log10[a[n]]], a[1] == 1}, a, 
  {n, 1, 20}]
```

gives

> `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30}`

#### Update 2

In response to the most recent comment made by the OP, I say: Now you have asked about a legitimate numerical issue. `Floor` indeed has trouble evaluating `Log[4]/Log[2]` and similar exact quantities. I have reported the problem to WRI tech support but am still awaiting a reply. A work around is:

```
RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == a[n] + 1 + Floor[Log2[a[n]]], a[1] == 1.0}, a, 
  {n, 1, 20}] // Rationalize
```

> `{1, 2, 4, 7, 10, 14, 18, 23, 28, 33, 39, 45, 51, 57, 63, 69, 76, 83, 90, 97}`

Note I use `a[1] == 1.0`, not `a[1] == 1`. That decimal point forces machine arithmetic and keeps `Floor` out of trouble.

Comment: I left out the all important `+1` in the recurrence relation. .

Comment: If `Log10` is replaced by `Log2` does your output produce the the desired data string?

Comment: @Leucippus. What is the desired string? You haven't indicated any "desired string" in your question. `For a[1] == 1, a[n + 1] == a[n] + 1 + Floor[Log2[a[n]]],` I get `{1, 2, 4, 7, 10, 14, 18, 23, 28, 33, 39, 45, 51, 57, 63, 69, 76, 83, 90, 97}`

Comment: The data string was the set of numbers you generated and presented. I have encountered `N::meprec: "Internal precision limit $MaxExtraPrecision = 50.` reached while evaluating Floor[Log[4]/Log[2]]"` and related for `Floor`. I changed the `$MaxExtraPrecision` to higher values and obtain the same result. If I use `Round@` I get the data set, but the 4th term should be a 7 and I get a 6. Any suggestions as to what can be done?

Comment: @Leucippus. Have supplied work-around.